# How to extract channel network from DEM file in QGIS and avoid mixing stream from road

Tags: qgis, hydrology, strahler

I am a bit new to QGIS world and want to extract catchment area and channels from a high resolution DEM file. I tried Strahler Order method available in my QGIS 3.22.9 but the results are not satisfactory. I guess roads are mixed with rivers and small channels. This is a view on a part of my DEM:
[image]

The resolution is not bad but exported 6th order channels are messy. This is the total network of channels:
[image]

And this is the street view of the area:
[image]

Comment: Do you have the paths of any of the actual streams/rivers in GIS already i.e. as a polyline file?

Comment: Dear @EdRollason, Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I do not have anything. I just wanted to rely on DEM and QGIS accuracy! But I can digitize actural streams and rivers. In case of having them, have can they help me?

Comment: If you had a network of the actual streams you could use the whitebox toolbox to burn the stream network into the DEM. That would breach the obstructions and force the streams to follow their mapped paths.

Comment: The problem you have is that your high resolution DEM does a really good job of representing channel obstructions like bridges and culverts.

Comment: @EdRollason, thanks for your help. The resolution of my DEM is making life hard for me! I mean I expected an easy strahler and later on catchment area model but unfortunately it did not happen. Can you please provide me with a detailed introduction to the whitebox toolbox. I am quite new to QGIS and can only follow simple instructions.

Comment: The user manual for whitebox is here: https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/preface.html